# DataView.RowFilter in DataTable does not return filtered records

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataview

I have a DataTable **dt**, in which 1200 records are coming.
Below is the code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = GetAccCode(c);
```

Now, using DataView I want to filter the record of **dt**, based on 1 column.
Below is the code:

**EDITED**

```
 DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.RowFilter = "AccountDescription LIKE '" + e.Text + "' " ;
    dv.RowFilter = "Isnull(AccountDescription,'NULL') <> 'NULL'";

    //dv.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;  
    if (dv.Count > 0)
    {
        dt = dv.ToTable(); 
    }
```

Full Code: 
**C# CODE:**

```
private const int ItemsPerRequest = 50;

    private static string GetStatusMessage(int offset, int total)
    {
        if (total <= 0)
            return "No matches";

        return String.Format("Items <b>1</b>-<b>{0}</b> out of <b>{1}</b>", offset, total);
    }

    public DataTable GetTable()
    {
        //  columns.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("AccountCodeID", typeof(Guid));
        table.Columns.Add("AccountDescription", typeof(string));
        // DataRows.
        table.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), "9830.58578 Furniture&Food counter ");
        table.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), "09.323232 New-release add ons");
        table.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), "84.238799 G&D - Depot from Outerjoin");
        table.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), "141.44445043-Random&Access-Memory hydero 048kkjug ");
        table.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), "142.85223 Account's hyqure");
        table.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), "324.989384934 F&D Admin-Dept Working ");
        table.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid(), "77.234434 Unique's Question why not's so");
        return table;
    }

    protected void ddlAccountCode_ItemsRequested(object sender, RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        string c = ddlCompany.SelectedValue.ToString();

        DataTable dt = GetTable();
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        string searchParamText = e.Text;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("AccountDescription LIKE '%{0}%'", searchParamText);
        //dv.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;

        int a = dv.Count;
        if (dv.Count > 0)
        {
            dt = dv.ToTable();
        }

        RadComboBox combo = (RadComboBox)sender;

        int itemOffset = e.NumberOfItems;
        int endOffset = Math.Min(itemOffset + ItemsPerRequest, dt.Rows.Count);
        e.EndOfItems = endOffset == dt.Rows.Count;

        for (int i = itemOffset; i < endOffset; i++)
        {
            combo.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(dt.Rows[i]["AccountDescription"].ToString(), dt.Rows[i]["AccountDescription"].ToString()));
        }

        e.Message = GetStatusMessage(endOffset, dt.Rows.Count); 
    }
```

**HTML Code:**

```
    <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblAcCode2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AccountCode") + " - " + Eval("AccountDescription")%>' Visible="false"> 
         </asp:Label>

         <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlAccountCode" runat="server" Height="200" Width="240" DropDownWidth="310" HighlightTemplatedItems="true" CausesValidation="true" OnItemsRequested="ddlAccountCode_ItemsRequested" ItemsPerRequest="10" EnableLoadOnDemand="True" ShowMoreResultsBox="true" EnableVirtualScrolling="true" Filter="Contains" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="AccountDescription" DataValueField="AccountCodeID">
         </telerik:RadComboBox> 

    </EditItemTemplate>
```

But everytime **dt** returns all 1200 records not the filtered record.

**Requirement:** When I click on RadComboBox, it goes into `_ItemRequested` event. I want that when I search any record in RadComboBox, and if the record is there in DataTable then it shall goto `GetStatusMessage` ELSE part, or if the searched record is not there in DataTable then it shall goto `GetStatusMessage` IF part.
To get the searched record of RadComboBox from DataTable, I am using DataView.RowFilter method but everytime when I type any text in RadCombo, it never return the searched value and always show DataView.Count =0

Please reply how to solve this issue. I am stuck from 2 days in it.

Comment: did you tried `dv.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;` after applying `RowFilter`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava: Thank you for the reply. But when I add your suggested line in my code (please check my posted question again , I had modified it) everytime `dv.count = 0` , And still I do not get filtered data when I do filtering. Please reply

Comment: try this `dv.RowFilter = "Isnull(AccountDescription,'NULL') <> 'NULL'";`

Comment: and just to make sure it must be filtering records please try `"AccountDescription LIKE  %'" + e.Text + "'%";`

Comment: @MohitShrivastava: Please check my edited code. When I try to use `dv.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;` line, everytime `dv.count=0` and when I use current edited code, everytime `dv.count=<total records of dt>`i.e.,1200  Please suggest what shall I change to get the desired result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86746/discussion-between-user3196511-and-mohit-shrivastava).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was using below code before but it was not working. Now it suddenly started working:

```
        DataTable dt = GetAccCode(c);
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        string txt = e.Text;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("AccountDescription LIKE '%{0}%'", txt);       
        int a = dv.Count;
        if (dv.Count > 0)
        {
            dt = dv.ToTable();
        }
```

Problem resolved. Thank you for the help @Mohit Shrivastava

Answer (score 7):

I believe this might solve your problem.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = GetAccCode(c);
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.RowFilter = "AccountDescription LIKE '%" + e.Text + "%'" ;
dv.RowFilter = "Isnull(AccountDescription,'') <> ''";

dv.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent;  
if (dv.Count > 0)
{
   dt = dv.ToTable(); 
}
```

Just for testing purposes you can also hard code the values and see if it changes the result. for example:

```
dv.RowFilter = "AccountDescription LIKE '%mo%'" ;
```

and omit or comment the line

```
//dv.RowFilter = "Isnull(AccountDescription,'') <> ''";
```

to see what results you get.

Comment: Dont know what is wrong going on. Everytime I get `dv.count=0` for filtered records. Also, `dv.RowFilter = "AccountDescription LIKE %'" + e.Text + "'%" ;` returns all the records 1200 in place of only filter records. I am stuck in this issue from 2 days..Unable to understand the problem. Please help

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Please check my posted question again, there I added the full code (under **Full Code** section) along with Requirement description. If any confusion in my requirement please let me know. Waiting for your reply

Comment: 1 more thing: When I hard code the `e.Text` in this line: `string searchParamText = e.Text;` it gives me expected output. But when I directly use this line it never give expected out put. This is the only problem im facing. If this is resolved my requirement will be done. Please reply

Comment: Friend then the problem is not with the code but with the input you are using. What is the value of `e.Text` when you debug.

Comment: `e.Text` value is whatever I type in RadComboBox. When I use `string searchParamText = e.Text;` it returns all the rows of DataTable in DataView.RowCount and when I hard code `e.Text` value it gives expected output. Please tel what is wrong in my code.

Comment: I can not hard code the value of RadCombo search text. And whatever I type in RadComboBox, I get its value in `e.Text` inside `_ItemRequested()` event. So only I am using it in my code. But don't know why it always return all the records of DataTable not the searched one. Please reply

Comment: Can u do something like this `RadComboBoxName.Text` instead of `e.Text`

Comment: For more you can have a look on this [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/populate-radcomboboxitemsrequestedeventargs-text-property) which will help u to extract the text of RADComboBox

Answer (score 1):

Try changing RowState

```
dv.RowStateFilter = DataViewRowState.CurrentRows
```